# c++: Transfer object from one thread to another

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a non-concurrent object of type `A` on heap. I have a shared pointer to it. I always use this object from the same thread, until I decide that I want to use it from another. `A` is not copiable and not movable. Application logic ensures that usage on thread #2 will start after usage on thread #1. I have many operations to do with it on thread #1 and I cannot foresee the amount of work or the exact time when the decision to transfer will be made.

My current idea is that after all the work I will `acquire()` and `release()` a `mutex` on thread #1 and then I will do the same on thread #2 with the same mutex before using the object. In theory this will ensure that everything is visible on thread #2 that happened on thread #1 with the benefit that I don't have to use mutexes or synchronization while I know that only thread #1 accesses the object.

Is this method sufficient? Are there any better? Is there an official name for this task?

This is an academic question.

Comment: I would just use a `std::condition_variable`.  Once you are done with `A` in the first thread notify it and that will let the other thread know it is good to go.

Comment: Does it have to be a shared pointer? A unique_ptr transfers ownership - would it possible to transfer ownership this way? (kind of thinking out loud - haven't thought through the intricacies...)

Comment: How does thread 2 know when to start working? Chances are, that whatever mechanism exists to let thread 2 out of the gate, it _may_ already provide the synchronization that you need to ensure that thread 2 sees a consistent, up-to-date version of the object.

Comment: @Rags, `std::unique_ptr<T>` isn't meant to help with memory visibility between threads.

Comment: You should provide more detail.  What are you trying to achieve?  What are the two threads for?  How do they work?

Comment: I may be differing from the question but this sounds like a bad design. How can you depend on this that thread one will finish and then thread 2 will start and then thread one again.
Use a thread-safe queue and push with thread one and pop with thread two(producer-consumer).

Comment: @SolomonSlow I know. Was just thinkibg that in this instance it might provide a workable method.

Comment: @PeterRuderman The queue has a mutex that needs to be acquired and released in order to add the item to the queue. And the same mutex needs to be acquired and released when consuming the queue. That is what ensures visibility on the new thread. Am I right? Which is my original idea. The question is academic, not about good practices, but about knowing the intrinsics better. I have a reason for asking this, but would lead the conversation far away for nothing. Would it be sufficient to increment an atomic on thread #1 and then increment it on thread #2 to achieve visibility?